# Obter caminho relativo para o diretório onde se encontra o arquivo index.php

Tags: php

Eu  tenho que fazer a navegação dentro do meu site com um menu, ae eu criei um arquivo com todo o codigo do menu, e nos arquivos q eu queria o menu eu dei um require_once "";
So que, nem todos os arquivos estao no mesmo diretorio do index
Ae eu quero um metodo q retorne o diretorio necessario para chegar ao index

Exemplo: 
Eu tenho uma pasta chamada folder e dentro desta pasta tem um arquivo chamado file.php, nesse arquivo eu usei o require_once para adicionar o menu, ae tem que ter um metodo dentro do arquivo menu.php q retornasse o diretorio para fazer a" linkagem" com os arquivos index.php, sobre.php
No caso teria q retornar "../index.php" para ter acesso ao mesmo

Tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consideremos a estrutura de pastas e arquivos:

```
public_html/
    folder/
        file.php
        menu.php
    index.php
    sobre.php
    contato.php
```

O diretório `public_html` será o *root* da sua aplicação. Você pode criar qualquer *link* relativo a este diretório iniciando a URL com uma barra `/`. O *link* abaixo sempre apontará corretamente para o arquivo `index.php` dentro do diretório *root*.

```
<a href="/index.php">Início</a>
```

Desta forma fica independente de qual é o arquivo que está exibindo o menu, o *link* será o mesmo. Se houver a necessidade de *linkar* arquivos em subpastas, basta fazer:

```
<a href="/folder/file.php">Arquivo</a>
```

O que precisa saber é que sempre o caminho `/` apontará para o diretório *root*. A partir dele você pode definir o caminho que desejar. Desta forma, o conteúdo do arquido `folder/menu.php` seria algo como:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/index.php">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="/sobre.php">Sobre nós</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contato.php">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado anderson pela a explicação !

Answer (score 0):

<sub>O $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] retorna o nome do arquivo do script que está executando,
 **relativa à raiz do documento**.</sub>

> Exemplo: Suponhamos que você esteja acessando o URL `http://www.exemplo.com/estoque/produto.php?id=5`   então $ _SERVER ['PHP_SELF'] retorna  `"/estoque/produto.php"`  no seu script.

Script para usar caminho relativo com notação ../

```
 $caminho = ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
 $quant = substr_count($caminho, '/');
 $quant=$quant-1;
 for ($k = 0; $k < $quant; $k++) {
   $relativo.="../";
 }
 echo "<a href=\"".$relativo."index.php\">index</a>";
```

O  script acima para o URL  `http://www.exemplo.com/estoque/produto.php?id=5`
produzirá `../produto.php`

Caso os arquivos do menu estejam na mesma:

```
   <a href=\"".$relativo."index.php\">Início</a>
   <a href=\"".$relativo."demo.php">Demo</a>
   <a href=\"".$relativo."chat.php">Chat</a>
```

Diretório 1 nível acima, produzirá

```
   <a href="../index.php\">Início</a>
   <a href="../demo.php">Demo</a>
   <a href="../chat.php">Chat</a>
```

Diretório 2 níveis acima, produzirá

```
   <a href="../../index.php\">Início</a>
   <a href="../../demo.php">Demo</a>
   <a href="../../chat.php">Chat</a>
```

E assim sucessivamente.

> A variável $relativo resolve para a index ou qualquer outro arquivo que esteja na raiz, e sua aplicação em outra pasta qualquer. Porém não poderá ser aplicado em outros links do menu se estes estiverem em outras pastas. Neste caso use uma barra / que indica desde a raiz.

```
<a href="../index.php">Início</a>
<a href="/pastaA/pastaB/demo.php">demo</a>
<a href="/pastaB/chat.php">chat</a>
```